# installing windows 7 after ubuntu

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning, windows-7

First I would like to note I don't have a lot of experience with Linux systems nor a lot about dual booting.

I have Ubuntu studio 14 installed and I tried to install Windows afterwards.

I have Ubuntu installed on a SSD and I have a 2.0 TB HD that I want to install Windows on.

I formatted the HD and tried to install Windows, but I get the following error:

```
setup was unable to create a new system partition...
```

I tried every way mentioned by this site and on other forums and blogs, but nothing worked the error is still present.

I'm not sure what to do...but I would rather not uninstall Ubuntu for Windows.

Comment: forgot to mention that I'm trying to install windows 7

Comment: Well, start yout ubuntu and install gparted `sudo apt-get install gparted`. Open gparted, select your 2.0TB HD and delete all partitions (backup your files before if you need). Then try to install Windows. Be careful, Windows will override your boot.

Comment: If you want to sure not to mess up your Ubuntu configuration, you could remove the SSD and install Windows on the HDD. Use windows to partition and format the 2 TB HDD. Microsoft is famous for not "seeing" filesystems created by other operating systems. Afterward you can re-install the SSD, boot Ubuntu and update grub to obtain dual-boot

Answer (score 0):

Run this in terminal:

`sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install gparted && sudo gparted`

It will ask you for your password once, then it will install a graphical partition editor.

In the top right-hand corner, there's a drop-down menu that'll let you choose the disk you want. Choose the HDD you want to install Windows on.

Then, from the top menu bar, choose Device ==> Create Partition table. A dialogue box will pop up with a warning. I gather from your question that you intend to wipe out all data on your 2TB HDD and put Windows on it. If this is the case, continue by clicking "OK". If not, you should update your question to reflect the partitioning scheme you desire on the 2TB HDD.

Choose "msdos". It'll take a minute to run.

You should now have ~2 TB of unallocated space. Right click the space, click "add new", then format it to "Fat16", "Fat32", "exfat" (if available), or "ntfs". Any one of those should do.

Then reboot your computer and try to install Windows on that HDD.

Answer (score 0):

You could Install Windows 7 on [VirtualBox](https://www.virtualbox.org/wiki/Linux_Downloads), if you dont want to go through the partioning and installation all over again.